# Change options in a drop-down list depending on another selected drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_options3) which you have a dropdown list and depending what you select, the next dropdown list will have different options.

I have my codes in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3hbovar/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="diffList" onchange="changeList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Difficulty --</option> 
  <option value="1">Easy</option> 
  <option value="2">Medium</option> 
  <option value="3">Difficult</option> 
</select> 

<select id="numbList"></select> 

<script>
var difficulty = {};
difficulty['1'] = [1,2,3];
difficulty['2'] = [4,5,6];
difficulty['3'] = [7,8,9];

function changeList() {
    var diffList = document.getElementById("diffList");
    var numbRange = document.getElementById("numbList");
    var selectDiff = diffList.options[diffList.selectIndex].value;
    while(numbRange.options.length)
    {
        numbRange.remove(0);
    }
    var diff = difficulty[selectDiff];
    if(diff)
    {
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < diff.length; i++)
        {
            var difficulty = new Option(diff[i], i);
            numbRange.options.add(difficulty);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm encountering is the next droplist is not showing any options. I've look through my codes many times and I still can't seem to find out what's wrong with it. Would someone mind looking over it and let me know?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/h3hbovar/3/) (tested only ib Chrome).

The one problem was here - *for* loop does not create nested scope in JS, so it shadowed global variable *difficulty*

```
for(i = 0; i < diff.length; i++) {
    var difficulty = new Option(diff[i], i);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's do it:

1. You should not use `onchange="changeList()"` on jsfiddle beause it wraps your code into the `onclick` handler and the `changeList` function does not visible from the outer scope.
2. You should use `diffList.value` for detect the currently selected value in the first selectbox: `var selectDiff = diffList.value;`
3. Do not name the new option variable `difficulty` - it overrides the `difficulty` variable from the outer scope. Name it `option`, for example: `var option = new Option(diff[i], i);`
4. Add the event listener for `diffList` from JS: `diffList.addEventListener('change', changeList)`

http://jsfiddle.net/h3hbovar/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary problem here was javascript scoping within functions.  If `difficulty` is defined outside the context of the function, it needs to be defined as a global by being attached to `window`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   

<select id="diffList" onchange="changeList()"> 
  <option value="">-- Difficulty --</option> 
  <option value="1">Easy</option> 
  <option value="2">Medium</option> 
  <option value="3">Difficult</option> 
</select> 

<select id="numbList"></select> 

<script>
window.difficulty = {};
window.difficulty['1'] = [1,2,3];
window.difficulty['2'] = [4,5,6];
window.difficulty['3'] = [7,8,9];

function changeList() {
    var diffList = document.getElementById("diffList");
    var numbRange = document.getElementById("numbList");
    var selectDiff = diffList.options[diffList.selectedIndex].value;
    while(numbRange.options.length)
    {
        numbRange.remove(0);
    }
    var diff = window.difficulty[selectDiff];
    if(diff)
    {
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < diff.length; i++)
        {
            var difficulty = new Option(diff[i], i);
            numbRange.options.add(difficulty);
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```